# Pass rails object value into span title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to pass an object value into the title of a span element however when I use the below code on hover #{campaign.status} is displayed rather than Aprroved or Rejected as is my intention.

```
%td.status-data= campaign.status == "Approved" ? '<span title="#{campaign.status}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green center"></span>'.html_safe : campaign.status == "Rejected" ? '<span title="#{campaign.status}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red center"></span>'.html_safe : campaign.status
```

Comment: I think if you make your code readable by removing those ternary operators in the view and use if-else then you yourself would find an answer. ;)

Comment: I've had conflicting report. Some people suggest ternary operators as they reduce the size of the code making the overall document more readable while others have taken your stance. By removing the ternary operator how does it affect that contained within the span element?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `haml` for views, So it should be like below.

```
%td.status-data
  - if campaign.status == "Approved"
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok.green.center{title: "#{campaign.status}"}
  - else
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove.red.center{title: "#{campaign.status}"}
```

**Note:** make sure your indentation is 2 space for `haml` view

OR you have to use in simple `html.erb`, it will be like below

```
<td class="status-data">
  <% if campaign.status == "Approved"%>  
    <span title="#{campaign.status}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green center"></span>
  <%else%>
   <span title="#{campaign.status}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red center"></span>
  <%end%>
</td>
```

Comment: Why was my code not working? Was it due to my use of ternary operators?

Comment: normally ternary looks like `condition ? true : false`, but have done `condition ? true : false : something else`, so after `something else` part is invalid for ternary

Comment: It was actually suggested to me to use this approach as an if elsif statement. What would the correct approach be?

Comment: `= campaign.status == "Approved"  ? "<span title='#{campaign.status}' class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok green center'></span>".html_safe : "<span title='#{campaign.status}' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove red center'></span>".html_safe
`

Comment: Would this not add glyphicon-ok if approved and glyphicon-remove if anything else. The problem is there are a number of status. Approved, rejected, new, on hold etc. This is why I was hoping for a if elsif else statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119026/discussion-between-hgsongra-and-eamonnmcelroy).